# Git post-update hook for every branch

Tags: git, githooks

From docs:

> `update`
>
> The `update` script is very similar to the `pre-receive` script, except
>   that it’s run once for each branch the pusher is trying to update

I need **multi-branch equivalent to post-receive**, not pre-receive.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The `post-receive` hook receives information about all branches being updated in the transaction.  E.g., if I push branches "master" and "devel" to a remote repository, the `post-receive` hook will see something like:

```
<old_devel_cid> <new_devel_cid> refs/heads/devel
<old_master_cid> <new_master_cid> refs/heads/master
```

Given that you have a list of branches being updated, you should be able to implement whatever logic is necessary.

Comment: Hm, thanks. This is complicated, because I have code that gets parameters and matches branch names. I will update only one by design